# PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/Mail.php'

Tags: php, drupal, pear

I am new to php and drupal.After i successfully installed pear and dependency files of pear i got error in log/error.log like as below

**PHP Fatal error:require_once():Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/Mail.php'(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/user/public_html/domainname.com/public/sites/all/modules/modulename/ modulename.module on line 93, referer: http://domainname.com/**

in my module these lines are

**require_once "/usr/share/php/Mail.php";**

**require_once "/usr/share/php/Mail/mime.php";**

i searched the files Mail.php and Mail/mime.php where these are installed by locate mail.php and locate mime.php

**locate mime.php**

**/usr/share/php/Mail/mime.php**

**locate mail.php**

**/usr/share/php/Mail/mail.php**

**/usr/share/php/Mail/sendmail.php**

i googled then i changed php.ini file.
in this file(php.ini)
;UNIX: "/path1:/path2"

**;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear**

again it shows same error.
what is the problem? what i want change? can any one help me from this

Comment: i think that /usr/share/php/Mail/mail.php differs from /usr/share/php/Mail.php. set proper paths in php file.

Comment: tthanks your approach.but till i am not getting answer

Answer (score 0):

[Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) and [Mail_mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_mime) are two different packages, so it might be that you have Mail_mime installed, but not Mail.

Install the mail package as root:

```
$ pear install mail
```